# rspec shows negative time

Tags: ruby, time, rspec

I'm running rails 3.2.1 with rspec 2.8.1 on ruby 1.9.3p0 and when running my tests it shows a negative time value. This is annoying as I'm trying optimise my tests.

```
Running: spec/models/transaction_spec.rb
................................................

Finished in -7603162.49414 seconds
```

I've tried updating rspec to 2.9.0 but this didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using the timecop gem? Make sure you `Timecop.return` after freezing. Either that or you're stubbing a date/time method somewhere.

Comment: 7603162 seconds is 87.9995 days. January the first was 87 days ago. Coincidence?

Comment: I bet he stubbed Jan 1st somewhere.

Comment: Yes I'm using Timecop, thanks, It's a very large project so I forgot I had that in there.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can do

```
time rspec filename.rb
```

But that would show the time it took for ruby itself to start up as well as how long the tests took.